# Pagination in Material UI in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui

I wanted to have a pagination depending on the length of the array.
Right now, the length of the array is 2. So the total pages should be 2.
I wanted to display them depending on each array by page. How do I do it?

[CLICK HERE FOR CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-b3p9qy?file=/demo.js)

**Expected output would be like:**

```
For page 1, it should display Robert Baker and its classification
For page 2, it should display John Jones, James Thomas and Lester Win and their classification
```

```
     <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <TableBody>
              {payload?.data?.map((data, index) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow hover key={index}>
                    <TableCell align="right">{data.fullname}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{data.classification}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={payload.length}
          rowsPerPage={1}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        />
      </Paper>
```

Comment: Pagination generally works by chunking, i.e. paginating, a flat array of data. From what you describe it sounds more like you want each array element of `payload` to be a "page" that renders a table of paginated entries. In other words, For page 1 it renders a page that renders a table with all the data from the ***first*** element in `payload.data`, and then for page 2 it renders a page that renders a table with all the data from the ***second*** element in `payload.data`. Does this sound like an accurate description?

Comment: @DrewReese. Yes thats right Drew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination generally works by chunking, i.e. paginating, a flat array of data. From what you describe it sounds more like you want each array element of `payload` to be a "page" that renders a table of paginated entries. In other words, for page 1 it renders a page that renders a table with all the data from the ***first*** element in `payload.data`, and then for page 2 it renders a page that renders a table with all the data from the ***second*** element in `payload.data`.

For this you'll need two pagination components, one for the page of `payload.data`, and the second for the page within *that* data.

Example:

```
import {
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableFooter,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TablePagination,
  TableRow
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Pagination } from "@material-ui/lab";

export default function EnhancedTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  // state for payload.data index
  const [dataPage, setDataPage] = useState(0);

  // state for paginated table data
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

  // when payload.data updates, reset table page
  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(0);
  }, [dataPage]);

  const onDataPageChange = (event, page) => setDataPage(page - 1);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => setPage(newPage);

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <TableBody>
              {/* select payload.data index */}
              {payload.data[dataPage]
                {/* paginate data */}
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((data) => (
                  <TableRow hover key={data.id}>
                    <TableCell align="right">{data.full_name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{data.classification}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter>
              <TableRow>
                <TablePagination
                  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]}
                  component="div"
                  count={payload.data[dataPage].length}
                  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                  page={page}
                  onPageChange={handleChangePage}
                  onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
              </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
      <Pagination
        count={payload.data.length}
        onChange={onDataPageChange}
        page={dataPage + 1}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit pagination-in-material-ui-in-react]

Comment: Hi Drew. `No need for this one the second for the page within that data`. Just use the `TablePagination` also.

Comment: @Joseph Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are saying there.

Comment: Hi Drew. Already fixed it. You can see it here https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-in-material-ui-in-react-forked-xcz7tm?file=/demo.js. This is the expected output. anyway can you help me since there's seems to be an error in console? `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>`.

Comment: @Joseph I've played around with a few things and looked through the MUI docs... I'm not sure right now what props need to be set/passed to get *something* between the `TablePagination` and the `Select` components to get the DOM element hierarchy correct.